How to pass dynamic JSON body in JMeter and LoadRunner
I have a payload with manager and reportees, based upon the manager, reportees count will get differ. For example, for 1 manager I will have 3 reportees details and another manager I have 2 reportees. How to pass this as request for an API so that reportees values should get changed based upon the given manager? I tried storing them in a separate files and call file name to generate requests, but that wouldn't be an ideal solution if I have to pass 1000 requests. Please share your thoughts.
Tried passing it through separate files but need a solution where I can parametrize the payload itself

For JMeter one of the possible options is generating request payload using JSR223 PreProcessor and Groovy language.
Groovy has built-in file reading and building JSON capabilities so you should be able to produce the payload basing on the number of entries in the file.
See the following materials:

Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON
Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?


You haven't specified the protocol, so I am going to assume Web/HTTP
Every payload in LoadRunner is a string.   Use the language of your virtual user to construct a string, JSON or not, with the parameters you need before submission.  LoadRunner virtual users can be built using multiple languages, from JavaScript to C, Java and VB.   So, the model you choose is "Your mileage  may vary."
If you have a dynamic number of JSON entries, then consider the use of web_custom_request.
